# Cron jobs with Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

Is there a way to schedule a task (function) to execute at a given date/time with Action Script 3.0? I mean something like `schedule(myFunction:Function, dateTime:Date)`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively per se.

SetTimeout as outlined in another answer is probably you're easiest bet. But if you had many things you wanted scheduled, here is a class that could manage it:  (it could be modified to use setTimeout instead of a timer, but I prefer timers)

```
public class Scheduler {
    public var time:Date;
    public var action:Function;
    public var parameters:Array;

    private var checkInterval:Number = NaN;
    public function get interval():Number { return checkInterval; };
    public function set interval(val:Number):void {
        checkInterval = val;
        if (schedules && (mainTimer && mainTimer.delay > val)) {
            mainTimer.delay = val;
        }
    }

    public function Scheduler(time_:Date, action_:Function, interval_:Number = NaN, parameters_:Array = null):void {
        time = time_;
        action = action_;
        checkInterval = interval_;
        parameters = parameters_;
    }

    //static stuff

    private static var mainTimer:Timer;
    public static function stop():void {
        if (mainTimer) {
            mainTimer.stop();
        }
    }

    public static function start():void {
        if (mainTimer && !mainTimer.running) {
            mainTimer.start();
        }
    }

    public static function get curInterval():Number { return (mainTimer) ? mainTimer.delay : 0; };

    private static var scheduleList:Vector.<Scheduler>;
    public static function get schedules():Vector.<Scheduler> { return scheduleList; };


    /**
     * Schedules a function to run at a certain time (with the margin of the interval)
     * @param   time - what time to run this passed action
     * @param   action - a function to call between the time passing, and the next interval
     * @param   interval - how often to check if the time has come, default is 1 second
     * @param   ... rest - parameters to pass to the action method
     * @return
     */
    public static function scheduleAction(time:Date, action:Function, interval:Number = NaN, ... rest):Scheduler {
        var s:Scheduler = new Scheduler(time, action, interval, rest);

        //if already old
        if (time.time < new Date().time) {
            action.apply(null, rest);
            return s;
        }

        if (!scheduleList) {
            scheduleList = new Vector.<Scheduler>();
        }

        scheduleList.push(s);

        if (!mainTimer) {
            mainTimer = new Timer(1000);
            mainTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTick);
            mainTimer.start();
        }

        if (!isNaN(interval) && interval < mainTimer.delay) {
            mainTimer.delay = interval;
        }

        return s;
    }

    private static function timerTick(e:TimerEvent):void {
        var tmpDate:Date = new Date();
        for (var i:int = scheduleList.length-1; i >= 0;i--){
            if (tmpDate.time >= scheduleList[i].time.time) {
                scheduleList[i].action.apply(null, scheduleList[i].parameters);
                removeSchedule(i);
            }
        }

        checkTimerNeeded();
    }

    private static function checkTimerNeeded():void {
        if (scheduleList && scheduleList.length < 1) {
            mainTimer.stop();
            mainTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTick);
            mainTimer = null;
            scheduleList = null;
        }
    }

    private static function removeSchedule(index:int):void {
        scheduleList.splice(index, 1);
        checkTimerNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Cancels a scheduled item
     * @param   s - the item to cancel
     * @return  returns true if the item was scheduled, false if the item wasn't scheduled
     */
    public static function cancelSchedule(s:Scheduler):Boolean {
        if (scheduleList) {
            var index:int = scheduleList.indexOf(s);
            if (index > 0) {
                removeSchedule(index);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static function status():void {
        trace("isRunning:", (mainTimer) ? mainTimer.running : null);
        trace("List Length:", scheduleList ? scheduleList.length : null);
    }
}
```

Use as follows:

```
Scheduler.scheduleAction(myDateToRunTheFunction, myFunctionToRun, howOftenToCheckTime, functionParameter1, functionParameter2, functionParameter2);
```

Comment: I like this implementation of the 'Scheduler' class, I'll try it! thanks @LondonDrugs

Comment: How did it work out?  The advantage of this, is you can pause all scheduled thing from happening (say if you have modal box up you don't want disturbed), cancel something, and always have access to what's in the queue.

Comment: thanks for the help but finally I used your suggestion in a simpler implementation using the Timer class specifically for the problem I wanted to solve.. nice contribution though

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it, it takes in the date to run the function and finds out how long there is to run the function then calls setTimeout

```
var date:Date = new Date(2012,9,13);
schedule(myFunction,date);

private function myFunction():void
{
    trace("Schedule function run");
}

private function schedule(func:Function,date:Date):void 
{
    var now:Date = new Date();

    if (date.time < now.time)
        return;
    var timetorun:Number =  date.time - now.time;
    setTimeout(func, timetorun);
}
```